# Is it better to have gold cfd contract or real bullion gold bars?

Tags: gold

Title says it all, I'd like to know the advantages and disadvantages of both.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if, and how, you intend to sell. If you never sell then physical gold would have a slight advantage. But if you anticipate selling within a handful of years (or months) then a fund would likely have greater liquidity. Greater liquidity usually means a higher amount on the sell price.